# How to get VS Code to list methods of object when multiple extensions are competing for tab complete

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

In VS Code, when writing the name of a method on an object, it seems to take a while for the method menu to pop up. I also am using github copilot, which is great, but it's suggestions often show first and I don't see the menu for the methods until I type some more letters.

Example, let's say I have the following line of code:

`my_json = My_Class(id=5).`

and I want to type the name of the method that returns some json. Gitlab copilot might suggest something like the following, where the 'get_json' portion is in grey and available for tab complete.

`my_json = My_Class(id=5).get_json()`

But, let's say the correct name for the method is 'get_object_json', I would have to type the following before the object method/attribute menu pops up

`my_json = My_Class(id=5).get_o`

Is there a way to manually open the object method/attribute menu? A keyboard shortcut? So that I can open it right after I have typed the period?

Similarly, sometimes I DO want the GitHub suggestion but, right as I hit tab, Pylance IntelliSense replaces the tab complete with the name of some variable or library, or global (i.e. some built-in exception class).

It would be great if there was a way to assign a specific key combo for tab complete of GitHub copilot. Like tab-option, or something, that will only complete the github copilot suggestion, if there is one.

Comment: I think it is similar to Emmet prefixes, if the prefix is recognized by Emmet you don't get other suggestions, like snippets or abc(words), when Emmet can't make sense of the text you get the other possibilities

Answer (score 0):

> It would be great if there was a way to assign a specific key combo for tab complete of GitHub copilot.

As I know of are the "[Keyboard shortcuts for GitHub Copilot](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/configuring-github-copilot/configuring-github-copilot-in-visual-studio-code#keyboard-shortcuts-for-github-copilot)".

They do include:

> Trigger inline suggestion <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd></kbd>:    `editor.action.inlineSuggest.trigger`</kbd>

Otherwise, in your case, Esc can dismiss a GitHub Copilot suggestion, after which you can type '`.`' and see if the "normal" completion takes place.